# Using CC2640 As USB Bluetooth Dongle

Tags: bluetooth, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy

I salvaged a CC2640 out of Bluetooth keyboard. I desoldered it in a attempt to reuse it. Can it be transformed to a USB Dongle adapter in any way? I'm doing this for knowledge, not for the outcome (It may be easier or cheaper to buy one, still want to do it)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It may be suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to *reprogram the flash* (http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraal3/spraal3.pdf). for this you can use *SmartRF Flash Programmer* and you need access to the pins of debug port (JTAG) or serial port (UART) and possibly there is a lock (fuse set).  the OEMs often set locks to ensure that nobody reads out the code with what they programmed their devices ... if you get access to the flash of the CC2640 you can reuse it. as the CC2640 has no USB port you can only make an USB dongle of it with an external chip i.e. a FTDI chip (connect the serial port of the FTDI with the serial port of the CC2640...)

Comment: Just what I was wandering!  I can build a JTag for it too! Thanks!